# React-router not changing routes with input onBlur event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using React, Redux, and React Router for an application and having trouble with using on `onBlur` input event in tandem with a route change.

I have a "SearchResults" component that presents a list of internal links. `SearchResults` only shows when the state `searchActive` is true.

```
<div>
    {props.searchActive ? <SearchResults /> : props.children}
</div>
```

`SearchResults` has a list of links rendered in a loop...

```
<Link key={Math.random()} to={r.path}>{r.name}</Link>
```

The input for the search (another, independent component) *sets `searchActive` to `true` during the `onFocus` event and `false` for the `onBlur` event.*

```
<input
    onFocus={() => {
        // dispatch Redux action (set "searchActive" to true)
        props.startSearch();
    }}
    onBlur={() => {
        // dispatch Redux action (set "searchActive" to false)
        props.endSearch();
    }}
/>
```

With this setup, when I click on a `Link`, the route *does not* change. However, if include a `setTimeout`, I get the desired behavior.

```
...

    setTimeout(() => {
        props.endSearch();
    }, 400)
...
```

---

**Update**

The `onBlur` action is hiding the SearchResults component and not registering the `Link` click. Is there any way I can register the Link click *before* doing the `onBlur` action?

---

*Why isn't react-router registering the route change on `Link` click when I dispatch a Redux action in the `onBlur` callback?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, because the `onBlur` event is fired before the `click` event is registered, i.e. your link disappears from the DOM before it can acknowledge it was clicked.

The `onMouseDown` event is fired before the `onBlur` event, so if you use it to initiate navigation, there is no need for magic timeouts.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/bp80sg7w/2/

Comment: Wow, this is great to know. Thanks for the great example ^